# Spoofing the OS version to trick a buggy installer

Tags: macos, system-information

I've been tasked with supporting a print shop using Kodak Prinergy 6.1, which is ancient. I need to install it on a new machine. The problem is that the installer has a bug where it compares OS versions lexicographically, so it doesn't grok that 10.13 is newer than the required minimum of 10.4.

Is there a way I can trick the installer into thinking I'm running 10.9?

Comment: Are you sure the software even runs on Intel? Is the installer an .app or a .pkg?

Comment: @patrix The app is known to work on machines that were upgraded to 10.10+.  It just won't install on them.

Comment: Good :-) .app or .pkg, or something else?

Comment: @patrix It's an .app.

Comment: Tried finding & just copying all the components over? I've had that work before, for dodgy old unsupported stuff [50/50 success rate]

Comment: @Tetsujin I've heard that may work. I was hoping to avoid it, but maybe it's the easiest or only way.

Comment: Can you add a link to the installer download?

Comment: Could you consider a VM ware with the old system and that software or even a dual boot ... have you considered hacking the installer to skip that check - did this with unix packages - can be fine or not depending ...

Comment: @grgarside I don't think Kodak distributes it, and there might be a licensing issue if I were to put it up somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Assuming that it's not baked into the installer, you can edit the version requirements for the app bundle.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17396/forcing-getting-app-to-run-on-lower-mac-osx-version)

Right click the app, hit Show Package Contents and open `Info.plist`. Look for a `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key, then change the value to your version of macOS.

[image]

You can also use Xcode's visual editor

[image]

It's possible you may need to do some more work though.

> `NSBundle` and `CFBundle` aggressively cache the contents of
>   application bundles to improve performance. Although you edited the
>   `Info.plist`, the Finder and Launch Services don't yet know that the
>   application is any different.
>
> Running the following command in Terminal to `touch` the application
>   bundle will force the Finder (and Launch Services) to re-register the
>   application, thereby noticing the changes you made to the
>   `Info.plist`:
>
> ```
> touch "/Applications/My Cool App.app"
> ```
>
> After running that, deselect the application, then reselect it in the
>   Finder, and then try launching it.
>
> Note that this won't necessarily guarantee that you'll be able to
>   launch the app.

In the case that it's baked into the app more deeply, [you can edit your macOS version at a system level.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153487/you-cannot-use-this-application-with-this-mac-os-version) Note you'll also need to disable SIP if you haven't already.

> 1. Boot in single user mode (hold down <kbd>s</kbd> during boot)
> 2. Make file system readable:
>
>    `/sbin/mount -wu /`
> 3. Go the `/System/Library/CoreServices` directory:
>
>    `cd /System/Library/CoreServices`
> 4. Edit `SystemVersion.plist`
>
>    `nano SystemVersion.plist`
> 5. Change the version strings (note that there may be two of these in the .plist), e.g.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>         <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
>         <string>14E46</string>
>         <key>ProductCopyright</key>
>         <string>1983-2015 Apple Inc.</string>
>         <key>ProductName</key>
>         <string>Mac OS X</string>
>         <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
>         <string>10.10.4</string>                // <<<
>         <key>ProductVersion</key>
>         <string>10.10.4</string>                // <<<
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```
>
> 6. Save and exit (<kbd>Control-O</kbd><kbd>Control-X</kbd>)
> 7. Reboot:
>
>    `reboot`

Comment: In this case the bug is baked into the installer. (It uses an old version of InstallAnywhere.) I haven't had a chance to try your second suggestion yet, but I'm accepting this answer because it seems very thorough.

Comment: Go ahead and try it and let me know what happens, I'll be happy to help!